# Recover data for mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Someone hijacked my mongodb.
Previously, I had a database name "comics", which contains many collections.
Now, the "comics" database is deleted, and instead, a new database is created with name "RECOVERY". In this database, there is only one collection with the same name "RECOVERY" with three records:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5da4ddf276d47f81f23a5b00"), "mail" : "whitx@gmx.com" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5da4ddf276d47f81f23a5b01"), "mail" : "whitx@gmx.com" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5da4ddf376d47f81f23a5b02"), "mail" : "whitx@gmx.com" }
```

When I checked the data folder at `/var/lib/mongodb/`, it has the following files:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 mongodb mongodb    49 May  6  2018 WiredTiger
-rw-r--r-- 1 mongodb mongodb    21 May  6  2018 WiredTiger.lock
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root     1001 Oct 14 22:35 WiredTiger.turtle
-rw-r--r-- 1 mongodb mongodb 53248 Oct 14 22:35 WiredTiger.wt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root     4096 Oct 14 22:32 WiredTigerLAS.wt
-rw-r--r-- 1 mongodb mongodb 36864 Oct 14 22:32 _mdb_catalog.wt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root    36864 Oct 14 22:33 collection-0--7743332637364831833.wt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root    32768 Oct 14 22:32 collection-6-2978034477663448513.wt
drwxr-xr-x 2 mongodb mongodb  4096 Oct 14 22:38 diagnostic.data
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root    16384 Oct 14 21:49 index-0-1498091654758504369.wt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root    32768 Oct 14 22:33 index-1-1498091654758504369.wt
drwxr-xr-x 2 mongodb mongodb  4096 Oct 14 22:33 journal
-rw-r--r-- 1 mongodb mongodb     6 Oct 14 22:32 mongod.lock
-rw-r--r-- 1 mongodb mongodb 36864 Oct 14 22:34 sizeStorer.wt
-rw-r--r-- 1 mongodb mongodb    95 May  6  2018 storage.bson
```

And I can see that the size of the folder is approximately 500Mb.
Is there any chance that I can recover my data?
Many thanks.

Comment: I assume `whitx@gmx.com` is trying to get your attention. Maybe he/she/they/whatever has your data? I further assume that you do not have something like what people call a "backup"?

Comment: Out of interest, provided you have authentication and TLS enabled, how did the perp manage to hijack your server?

Comment: No, I don't have a backup. The server contains data for my mobile app.
Is there anything I can do with the files left in the data folder?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I'm using a Droplet from digitalocean and I guess it is the issue from mongodb though I've set `bindIp: 127.0.0.1`

Comment: Then I have bad news: If the perp was able to hijack your MongoDB, it is VERY likely the perp hijacked the machine as well and/or your code is subject to an injection vulnerability.

Comment: No backup, no recovery. If you had a (substantially) delayed replica set member... maybe. But since your MongoDB was bound to 127.0.0.1, there is no chance for that. Furthermore, I sincerely doubt that MongoDB caused this issue. Weak passwords, lack of brute force protection etc are more likely the reason.

Comment: 'When I checked the data folder at /var/lib/mongodb/'  => Are you sure it's your 'real data directory? By default, mongoDb stores data in /data/db. And try to check the journal, to understand what happened.

Comment: @matthPen Yes, because I ran the mongodb with `--dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb/`.
Previously, I used the default path (`/data/db`), but after some time, the folder data was lost (probably attacked as well).